# java stream sort with string comparator ignoring case

Tags: java

```
hotels.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Hotel::getCity)
                       .thenComparing(hotel -> hotel.getName().toUpperCase())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

May I ask if there is a more concise way to write `.thenComparing(hotel -> hotel.getName().toUpperCase())`, I've found a `String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` but how do I use this comparator on `hotel.getName()`.

**update:**
Applied @Arnaud Denoyelle 's suggestion.

```
hotels.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Hotel::getCity)
                       .thenComparing(Hotel::getName, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It looks better.

Comment: Great question. The title should be more accurate so people can search for it later. I can't come up with anything right now (long work day :) )

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` is a `Comparator<String>` but you are trying to compare some `Hotel`.

You can get a `Comparator<Hotel>` like this :

```
// Map hotel to a String then use the Comparator<String>
Comparator.comparing(Hotel::getName, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
```

Then, if you only need to sort, you don't need to use a `Stream`, you can sort directly :

```
hotels.sort(Comparator.comparing(Hotel::getName, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER));
```

So, with the first comparison criteria, the code becomes :

```
hotels.sort(
  Comparator.comparing(Hotel::getCity)
            .thenComparing(Hotel::getName, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should provide another Comparator to the *thenComparing* chained method like so:

```
hotels.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Hotel::getCity)
            .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Hotel::getName, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
```